# Converting conditional series assignment to custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I'm trying to to introduce a new column into my data series.

I know how to use np.where() to make this work or simply a for loop but want to try the def function plus a for loop.

However, when i use def function plus the for loop, I always ended up with KeyError: 0. I want to compare the number in the Stats to 1, if it is greater than 1, my new column will have the value True, and it less than 1, the value would be False.

Here's my code:

```
def compare(a,b):
    if a > b:
        return True
    else:
        return False 


df.Comparison = {}  

for i in range (len(df)):  
    df.Comparison[i].apply(compare, (df.Stats[i],1))
df
```

Comment: hi, the indentation seems very broken. Can you fix it please? (I ust fixed the formatting so it appears as code) Also what is `df`? dataframe? that isn't a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already know how to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Comparison'] = np.where(df['Stats'] > 1, True, False)
```

But `np.where` is redundant, as you can assign a Boolean series directly:

```
df['Comparison'] = df['Stats'] > 1
```

If you want to use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a custom function, note the loop is "hidden" in the Pandas method. So you don't need to write a `for` loop yourself.

```
def compare(val, k):
    return val > k

df['Comparison'] = df['Stats'].apply(compare, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it with np.where before and worked. But realized that I was asked to use def & apply for this. I will reference your apply suggestion and try it.